# Error using amsmath aligned in multicolumn table

Tags: tables, align, amsmath

I have a table with some data. At the bottom, I would like to include two sets of aligned equations.

I can do this as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c}
        \textbf{Column 1}   & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\
        Row 1           & 1                 & 4 \\
        Row 2           & 2                 & 5 \\
        Row 3           & 3                 & 6 \\
      $\begin{aligned}
      a &=   5 \\
      b &=   7 \\
      c &=   9 \\
      \end{aligned}$ 
      &
      $\begin{aligned}
      d &=   3 \\
      e &=   3 \\
      f &=   3 \\
      \end{aligned}$ \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, the output is that the equations are left justified. I would like to centre them across the width of the table.

I have tried using the `\multicolumn` feature but that throws an error:

> Missing } inserted

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c}
        \textbf{Column 1}   & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\
        Row 1           & 1                 & 4 \\
        Row 2           & 2                 & 5 \\
        Row 3           & 3                 & 6 \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{
      $\begin{aligned}
      a &=   5 \\
      b &=   7 \\
      c &=   9 \\
      \end{aligned}$ 
      &
      $\begin{aligned}
      d &=   3 \\
      e &=   3 \\
      f &=   3 \\
      \end{aligned}$ \\
      }
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The error seems to be related to `\multicolumn` and the use of `}`, but I can't resolve by inserting or removing them (it also doesn't make sense as there appear to be the correct number of curly braces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that compile :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c}
        \textbf{Column 1}   & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\
        Row 1           & 1                 & 4 \\
        Row 2           & 2                 & 5 \\
        Row 3           & 3                 & 6 \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{
      $\begin{aligned}
      a &=   5 \\
      b &=   7 \\
      c &=   9 \\
      \end{aligned}$ 

      $\begin{aligned}
      d &=   3 \\
      e &=   3 \\
      f &=   3 \\
      \end{aligned}$ 
      } \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The problems where :

1. A `&` between the two `aligned` environment, even if they were in the same column
2. The last `\\` was placed inside the `multicolumn` environment, but it needs to be placed outside of it...

I hope it may help.